# Problems with v1/queryContext needed for SpagoBI integration

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, spagobi

In version 1.7.0 of Orion CB running the docker version in Docker for Windows, 
if I create a simple object doing POST http://localhost:1026/v1/updateContext

with the body:

```
{
    "contextElements": [
        {
            "type": "Car",
            "id": "myNewCar",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "maxSpeed",
                    "type": "integer",
                    "value": "220"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updateAction": "APPEND"
}
```

I get the answer:

```
{
  "contextResponses": [
    {
      "contextElement": {
        "type": "Car",
        "isPattern": "false",
        "id": "myNewCar",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "name": "maxSpeed",
            "type": "integer",
            "value": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      "statusCode": {
        "code": "200",
        "reasonPhrase": "OK"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, if I do POST http://localhost:1026/v1/queryContext with the same headers and the same components with the body

```
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Car",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "myNewCar"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get the following:

```
{
  "errorCode": {
    "code": "404",
    "reasonPhrase": "No context element found"
  }
}
```

Which shouldn't be problematic (I can query the entities with v2 API, for instance) if it wasn't needed for integration with data representation tools such as SpagoBI as documented in http://spagobi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/NGSI/README/

What can I do? I am doing something wrong with the context provision?

Thanks!

Comment: Doing a quick test (see https://gist.github.com/fgalan/807c016f0c53c77c037bcab4939668ae) I have been unable to reproduce your problem. Could you provide exact detail of the HTTP requests and responses at the wire, please? Including headers, URL, verb, status code, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I was using a imported Postman collection of the API (Downloaded from https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/tree/develop/doc/apiary/v2) and accidentally I was using the header Fiware-Service.

You are right and your tests work properly.

Thanks for the prompt reply!!